# Saving values from hidden fields 

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, vb.net

I have a page that's used by two different users. If the logged in user is 'user1' i display all 8 fields and if its 'user2' i display 7 out of the 8 fields. This is the html code i use to hide the one field from user2.

```
 <%If User1 Then%>   
   <tr>
      <td>
         <cc1:Label ID="lblTextBox1" runat="server" />
         <cc1:TextBoxId ID="txtTextBox1" runat="server" LabelId="lblTextBox1" Columns="20" />
     </td>    
  </tr>
<%End If%>
```

Now, when the aspx.vb page loads, it populates all these controls together, but this one field remain hidden because of the above html code. When the save button on the page is clicked, the save method dioes not try to distinguish between user1 and user2, but extract values from all the controls and saves.

My problem is when user2 'saves', the values of the 'hidden' textbox isbecoming null, though at the time the other controls were populated, this field also waspopulated. Somehow the values became '' at the point am saving it

Why is this happening like this? What is the best solution/work-around to this?

Comment: Could you please post the actual markup? What you posted is not valid.

Comment: thnks for that..i have been trying to do that myself!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using render blocks, have you thought about setting the visibility in the code?

Comment: I wished to do that..but this is an application that's been existing for long and is a little complicated with too many controls and blocks like this. But is this issue happening because  html block is being rendered like this?

Comment: Probably not - what's *supposed* to happen is when your If statement evaluates to true, that block appears in the page. When it's false, it shouldn't be rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlForUser2" runat="server">
<tr>
    <td>
        <cc1:Label ID="lblTextBox1" runat="server" />
        <cc1:TextBoxId ID="txtTextBox1" runat="server" LabelId="lblTextBox1" Columns="20" />
    </td>    
</tr>
</asp:Panel>
```

and in the code behind:

```
if(Page.User.Identity.Name.Equals("user2"))
    pnlForUser2.Visible = true;
```

or use shorthand operators `??`

Comment: I would suggest using a `PlaceHolder` rather than a panel, as a panel generates a `div` tag and won't be valid HTML

Comment: The textbox is not retaining its value even if the visbility is set to false. No, I am not manually clearing it by mistake.

Comment: @user1191463 do you have something like `if(!Page.IsPostBack())` in the `Page_load`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty workaround would be to explicitly save the value of that control into ViewState or a Session and manually repopulate it.  The issue probably stems from all the classic ASP style code blocks on the page.

Comment: unless, i am doing something silly- this is not working even if i remove the html code block and use visibility property of the control. the value still becomes blank!

Comment: It could be an issue in the custom control then.  Is there anything in the cc1:TextBoxId control code that might be causing issues?

Comment: there shouldn't be. let me try one asp.net textbox and update

Comment: not working with asp:TextBox either.. the value is still becoming blank!

Comment: Could the issue be related to the population of data in the textboxes?  By that I mean, are you assigning that textbox a value from user1 - who doesn't exists when user2 is interacting with the form.  If not, I am baffled as to why it would be clearing out.

Comment: no..the values are entered by user1 and then saved to db. then user2 logs in..he doesnt see this field. Could it be that values of 'invisible'or 'disabled' fields automatically get cleared or something?

Comment: I wouldn't think so as even hidden fields are saved in viewstate.  There is a chance that the if block on the front end is causing issues with viewstate because the control rendering is stopped by that block, and not by the standard visible="false".